# iOS ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize wildly inefficient

Tags: ios, memory, gif

I am developing a simple image processing app which includes one feature which involves the transformation of a GIF in UIImage format to NSData. So I am using a CGImageDestination to handle this process. However, the memory used by the `CGImageDestinationFinalize` call consistently induces spikes between 100-400MB, even though the GIFs are never more than 4MB in size (and usually ~100KB).

This wouldn't be an issue, except this often crashes the app and/or creates the error:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19c1b2a80> { count = 1, contents =
"XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19c1b2e78> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

What's going on? Is GIF conversion supposed to be this intense? Or are Apple's libraries poorly developed? Is there any way around this?

[image: Profiler]

I am using https://github.com/mattt/AnimatedGIFImageSerialization for image conversion.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I wish... are you getting the same issue?

Comment: Ultimately we ended up lowering the resolution